# Get a lambda argument from annotation

Tags: scala, reflection, lambda, annotations

Assume we have an annotation:

```
@scala.annotation.meta.field
class MyAnnotation(param: String => String) extends StaticAnnotation
```

According to Remi T's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23046958/accessing-an-annotation-value-in-scala), if `param` was just a `String`, we could extract it this way:

```
a.tree.children.tail.collect({ case Literal(Constant(id: String)) => id }).headOption
```

But how can we extract and use a **lambda expression**? It is a `Function(params, body)` where `params` is an arguments list and `body` is a `Tree` representing function's body.
It's possible to convert the whole function's `Tree` to `String` and then use an interpreter, but it is SO ugly solution (and I couldn't do even this due to some problems with classpath during instantiating the interpreter, none of advices I found worked).

Comment: Have you tried `c.eval(c.Expr[String => String](functionTree))`?